# Quelle est l'origine de "One again a bistoufly" ?

Tags: expressions

J'ai déjà fait une petite recherche mais rien n'est certain:
http://chroniquesdunfuturjournaliste.blogspot.co.uk/2012/04/one-again-bistoufly.html

"one again" ou "wanagaine" pourrait en fait être "I won again" qu'aurait proclamé Jeanne d'Arc lors de la bataille d'Orléans (très ancienne expression du coup).

"bistoufly" serait "best to fly" en relation avec les kamikaze, mais une rapide recherche en anglais ne montre aucun lien avec les pilotes japonais ni entre les deux parties de l'expression française.
D'après une réponse apportée cette combinaison aurait été popularisé par le Franck Dubosc qui se serait inspiré d'une connaissance.

Pour aller plus loin il faudrait se rapprocher du comédien, ou questionner des  anciens pilotes français de la 2GM ayants reçus des instructions en anglais.
Une autre possibilité serait à mon avis que Jeanne d'Arc ait dit "I won again and it's best (for the British) to flee !". Mais je ne sais pas comment le flee serait devenu fly.

Comment: One again a bistoufly ? J'aurais dit plutôt "à la wanagain and bistoufly", parce qu'on dit encore "j'ai rien préparé, j'y vais à la wanagain".

Comment: Il n'y a pas de consensus sur l'orthographe.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about french language.

Comment: Ah non et c'est à propos de quoi alors ??

Comment: « One again a bistoufly » n'est certainement pas du français ! Donc, je ne vois pas comment on pourrait en trouver l'origine dans la langue française.

Comment: @Toto Bien qu'elle s'appuie sur du vocabulaire anglais, l'expression « y aller *à la one again* » n'est utilisée qu'en France. On peut difficilement dire qu'il s'agit d'anglais alors que j'imagine qu'elle rend perplexes les anglophones. Un peu comme un smoking, un parking, faire du footing, jouer au foot ou un tennisman.

Comment: @jlliagre: C'est possible, mais, personnellement, c'est une expression que je n'ai jamais entendue.

Comment: @toto Oui, elle n'est pas très courante et j'ai été étonné de la retrouver ici. Je l'ai surtout entendue dans les années 70/80 dans le parler marseillais.

Comment: @Toto : « à la one again », je l'ai entendue, mais il y a longtemps, de l'argo désuet ? Apparemment, combinée avec le « bistoufly » elle est apparemment utilisée par Frank Dubosc et c'est de là que sort les histoires de Jeanne d'Arc & de Kamikaze l'auteur de la question (un petit lien aurait été utile). La « francisation » des termes anglais oraux est intéressante et je trouve qu'elle a sa place ici, c'est une étymologie contemporaine dira-t-on ? Après tout, « barbare » trouve une origine similaire (mauvaise compréhension, reproduction vague des termes étrangers).

Comment: Ce [document](http://www.guichetdusavoir.org/viewtopic.php?f=220&t=47917) recense ces propos bizarres tout en mentionnant heureusement _cependant aucune source historique fiable ne semble corroborer ces versions des faits._ Les [archives](https://books.google.com/books?id=ul8NX6_HneoC&vq=anglais&dq=(15%20mars%201431)%20jeanne%20d'arc&pg=PA251#v=snippet&q=anglais&f=false) rapportant ses propos lors de son procès semblent à mon avis incompatibles avec l'idée qu'elle se soit exprimée ainsi. Elle y dit que l'apparition de Sainte Marguerite ne s'exprimait pas en anglais dans tous les cas... Merci.

Answer (score 10):

Un début de réponse dans une [interview de Frank Dubosc en 2008 dans Le Parisien](http://www.leparisien.fr/franck-dubosc-le-sobre-je-sais-pas-faire-02-04-2008-3298409617.php):

> — Beaucoup de fans se demandent ce que veut dire « **One again et bistoufly** ».
>
> — Rien. C'est une phrase que j'ai piquée à José, mon éclairagiste. Chaque fois que je le dis sur scène, c'est comme un cri de ralliement avec mon équipe technique. La prochaine, ce sera « Swing, love and kiss ».

Il faudrait donc retrouver ce José (que je soupçonne d'être d'origine marseillaise) pour avoir le fin mot de l'histoire...

Comment: Intéressant, oui il faudrait le retrouver pour savoir ce que veut dire bistoufly, car "best to fly" n'évoque rien de particulier aux anglophones.

Comment: @user2534 Qu'est-ce que tu comprends pas dans "ça veut rien dire" ? On peut très bien inventer des expressions, on le fait tout le temps. Pourquoi ça doit avoir une origine, venir de quelque part ? L'origine ça peut juste être "un truc random qui sonne anglais"

Comment: Il n'y a pas de raison particulière pour que ça doive évoquer quoi que ce soit aux anglophones. Je doute que José soit anglophone. **Bistoufly** est peut-être simplement une évolution de **bistouquette**... :-)

Comment: @TeleportingGoat Je ne crois pas que les expressions naissent de cette manière, mais si tu as des exemples je t'écoute. Une expression a un sens qui vient en partie de l'origine des mots qui la compose et de l'autre partie de ce que l'auteur veut exprimer. "un truc random qui sonne anglais" aurait defacto pour origine une phrase anglaise déjà entendue.

Comment: @jlliagre si le lien avec les kamikaze est vrai alors "best to fly" évoquerait forcément quelque chose à la marine américaine.

Comment: Il n'y a aucun lien avec les kamikazes. Les articles qui évoquent ça ou Jeanne d'Arc sont évidemment des blagues, des fakes... Un mot ou une expression peut très bien naître de l'imagination d'une seule personne, par exemple le **schmilblick** crée par Pierre Dac dans les années 50.

Comment: @jlliagre Pourquoi évidement ? c'est vrai qu'à y regarder 2 fois c'est as très sérieux, mais il y a forcément une origine. On voit bien avec schmilblick que l'auteur s'inspire du mauvais parler allemand pour être sûr de ne donner aucun sens, d'ailleurs selon lui ça peut être n'importe quoi et vouloir tout dire.  Du coup ce mot n'est jamais utilisé ailleurs que dans l'expression "faire avancer le schmilblick" qui ne s'inspire pas du dit mot mais d'une mise en scène.

Comment: 1. Évidemment car ces explications ne tiennent pas la route, sont inventées de toutes pièces puisqu'elles ne font pas référence à l'éclairagiste de Frank Dubosc qui a sans guère de doute inventé le mot *bistoufly* inconnu auparavant. 2. Le yiddish est une langue germanique, pas « du mauvais allemand ». 3. Schmilblick n'est pas utilisé que dans la phrase « c'est pour faire avancer le schmilblick » qui n'est apparue qu'une vingtaine d'années plus tard. On peut aussi simplement dire schmilblick pour remplacer truc, machin.

Answer (score 1):

Je suis quasiment sûr que l'expression a été inventée de toutes pièces par Franck Dubosc, je vois pas pourquoi elle aurait besoin d'avoir une origine.

Je crois que j'ai trouvé le même article que toi, mais je pense pas que ce soit une source fiable.

---

J'ai fait des recherches pour expliquer mon résultat :

D'abord, [voilà](http://chroniquesdunfuturjournaliste.blogspot.fr/2012/04/one-again-bistoufly.html) ce que j'ai trouvé comme article. Ça parle de Jeanne d'Arc et de Kamikazes, il y a des chances que ce soit celui-là. Il y a aucune source, aucune explication, l'auteur semble sortir les infos de nulle part. Beaucoup d'autres pages essayant d'expliquer les origines citent cette page.

"Yahoo avait déjà trouvé la clé de l'énigme." Ah bon ? Où est le lien de la discussion où ils ont trouvé la clé ?

On nous explique que Jean d'Arc *aurait* dit "won again" contre les anglais. Ah. Donc apparement l'expression aurait été utilisée depuis la guerre de 100 ans, et hop ça devient une expression en français trouvée dans aucun texte et utilisée uniquement par Franck Dubosc. Logique.

J'ai trouvé un autre [site](http://www.mtgfrance.com/viewtopic.php?t=18268#) qui sort aussi des infos de nulle part sans source, c'est peut-être de là que viennent les infos du premier article.

D'ailleurs tous les résultats pour "won again Jeanne d'Arc" retournent vers des sites qui parlent de l'origine de l'expression, ça semble exister nulle part ailleurs.

Je vais m'arrêter là et pas parler des kamikazes, tout ça pour dire que je pense que l'origine à Jeanne d'Arc n'a aucun sens, c'est une explication ad hoc qui apporte plus de questions que de réponses.

Comment: C'est difficile de créer une expression de toute pièce. Il y a toujours une origine car c'est fait de plusieurs choses connues. On connait déjà l'origine de la première partie, manque celui de la seconde.

Comment: @user2534 Sources sur l'origine de la 1ère partie ?

Comment: Ok retour à la case départ alors.

Answer (score 1):

Je suis très étonné de lire que certaines personnes pensent que cette phrase de Frank Dubosc peut avoir un sens. C'est simplement des sons avec une sonorité un peu anglophone pour donner à son personnage l'air d'un prétentieux qui ne sait pas vraiment parler correctement en anglais.

Comme on ferait un nasal *onnngggg hong hong* pour imiter le français (allo allo style).  C'est vraiment, Very funny !

Merci beaucoup pour les corrections!  C'est apprécié.

Comment: Qu'en sais tu ?

Comment: Presque rien!  Et toi?

Comment: Ah oui je vois. Les américains m'en parlait tout le temps des pseudo-imitation de français des Simpsons. Ils n'avaient pas l'air de comprendre que, doublé en français ça n'avait aucun sens bien sûr. Et oui chercher à tout prix un sens à des phrases en faux anglais est un peu risible!

Answer (score 1):

En fait l’expression vient des chanteurs de bals des années 70 qui pouvaient chanter un répertoire de 50 chansons pop dans la soirée sans connaître 3 mots d’anglais. Ils chantaient en « yaourt » dans des sonos pourraves et personne n’avait rien à foutre si les paroles étaient ok. One again c’est once again et pistoufly c’est peace to fly. Les mecs interchangaient les paroles et ça passait crème. De toute façon on allait au bal pour choper, pas pour écouter du Shakespeare.
L’expression est devenue culte dans le milieu ( roadies, backliners, musicos, producteurs ) et désigne un ringard ou une situation merdique qu’on peut rencontrer au hazard des concerts.

Comment: Il y a une source pour « peace to fly » ou est-ce plutôt spéculatif ?

Answer (score 1):

« A la ouaneguène (bistouflaï) », expression marseillaise de la fin des années 70, qui en s’appuyant sur les sonorités anglosaxonne de « One again » (peace to fly) désigne une façon de s’y prendre à la fois improvisée, vite-fait et un peu en douce mais tjrs impromptue tout en se donnant un air classe et entendu… bref compliquée à traduire en français classique  Dubosc l’a popularisée mais sans la référence…